# Create a google sheet SEQUENCE with given sum of numbers

Tags: google-sheets, sequence

Need help:

I have a number (let's say 550) and need to create a perfect distributed SEQUENCE of length N where SUM of numbers will give this number (550).

Something like: 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100

The only input I have is the length of sequence and the final sum of it's numbers.

Thank you.

Comment: Since the formula for the sum of an arithmetical progression is Sn
=
n/
2
[
2
a
+
(
n
−
1
)
d
]  there must be an infinite number of possible series containing n terms which add up to Sn  for different values of a and d.

Comment: But if we assume that you are looking for integer values of a and d, it is straightforward to express a (say) in terms of d and step through (say the first 100 values of d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here are some possible starting values (a) and increments (d) that satisfy the conditions where the number of terms n is 10 and the sum S is 550:

Using the formula

```
=MAKEARRAY(S/n,2,LAMBDA(r,c,if(c=1,r,2/(n-1)*(S/n-r))))
```

The formula is obtained by re-arranging the [standard formula for an arithmetic progression](https://www.cuemath.com/sum-of-arithmetic-sequence-formula/) to get d (the increment) in terms of a (the starting value, S (the sum) and n (the number of terms):

[image]

[image]

Here are the integer pairs using

```
=lambda(pairs,filter(pairs,index(pairs,,2)=int(index(pairs,,2))))(MAKEARRAY(S/n,2,LAMBDA(r,c,if(c=1,r,2/(n-1)*(S/n-r)))))
```

[image]

Here are the actual series using

```
=lambda(intpairs,makearray(rows(intpairs),n,lambda(r,c,index(intpairs,r,1)+(c-1)*index(intpairs,r,2))))(lambda(pairs,filter(pairs,index(pairs,,2)=int(index(pairs,,2))))(MAKEARRAY(S/n,2,LAMBDA(r,c,if(c=1,r,2/(n-1)*(S/n-r))))))
```

[image]

It can be verified that each series totals to 550.

Once you have the values of a and d, you can also use Sequence to generate the results:

```
=sequence(1,n,F10,G10)
```

[image]

Comment: Tom, thank you. Trying to understand everything written by you )). Is there a chance you can share the working table of this?

Comment: Yes, here is the link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iMjczx-_UO8LEUJQg4NNeaWBC9LR7rVbydySnU9j5uA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In general, I got everything you explained. Thenk you very much because you helped me with the final formula I needed )

=INDEX(SEQUENCE(length;1;1)*2*sum/length/(length+1);;)

Answer (score 1):

```
=INDEX(SEQUENCE(length;1;1)*2*sum/length/(length+1);;)
```

Comment: OK this is the special case where a (the first term) = d (the common difference) or in other words the set of positive integers 1,2,3...n (whose sum is n/2*(n+1) ) times a constant of which 10,20..100 is an example.

Comment: As expected there will exist whole-number series where a<>d where there is no series such that a=d - for example, S=63, n=9 where there is a series 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11

Answer (score 0):

if your issue is to divide value `x` into equal chunks `y` try:

```
=INDEX(SEQUENCE(B1, 1)*A1/B1)
```

[image]

or starting from 0:

```
=INDEX(SEQUENCE(B1, 1, 0)*A1/(B1-1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but it's not what I needed. IT is just a sequence which ends with given number.

What I need is a sequence which SUM gives the number (550 in my case)